# c++ How to convert String to int (ascii code to value);

Tags: c++

i have been trying to make a program that checks if a national identification number is valid how ever i have run into a issue and i can't find an answer anywhere.
  I am using a string to store the users input of the identification code and i need to somehow covert the string to int keeping the symbol instead of getting an ascii value.

Example:
(lets say the user inputs the string persKods as 111199-11111
the 5th symbol is 9 so the year value should output as 9 instead of 54 which is its ascii value)

```
int day,month,year;
year=this->persKods.at(4);
cout << year; // it outputs 54 instead of 9 :/
```

Comment: That's interesting, I would expect 57.

Comment: `persKods.at(4) - '0'`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to ascci value of '0'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string str="111199";
    int test = str.at(4) - '0';

    cout<<test;

    return 0;
}
```

For more information [link](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/68260/&grqid=AyAOwLBS&hl=en-IN)